# spark map function with pyspark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to implement map with pyspark by using following code:

```
rdd1=sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
rdd2=rdd1.map(lambda x:x+5)
rdd2.collect()
```

but when I execute this code then throwing following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your executors can't find the python executable. Are you sure it's installed on all of the data nodes and have you set your `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` variable properly?

Comment: yes.. I have set all enviromental variable correctly.  i have set anaconda path also.

Comment: Are both your python and pyspark executables in your `PATH`?